# Azure pipelines: New pipeline - The string must have at least one character. Parameter name: contents

Tags: azure

I want to create a new pipeline in the azure devops services. I can select a github repo but the next step (selecting a yaml file) throws this error:

Image: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nztTE.png)

```
The string must have at least one character. Parameter name: contents
```

When I inspect the website I see this error message in the console:

```
ContributionData unavailable for 'ms.vss-build-web.recommended-configuration-data-provider', ExceptionType: 'ArgumentException', Reason: The string must have at least one character. Parameter name: contents, StackTrace: null
```

Image: [Error message in chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp6hs.png)

Couldn't find anything about this error and the error message itself is somehow cryptic.

Has someone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you YAML syntax is correct, you may try to "Edit" and "Save and Run" the pipeline in GUI for the first run.

See https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My YAML was correct and the pipeline was working the next day without any changes, strange...

Comment: I just got the same error. I guess I'll try tomorrow. :D